# Program "killed" in the Virtual Machine [Ubuntu 14.04 in Windows 8.1]

Tags: vmware-player, vmware-workstation

I am using VMware Workstation 12 Player (with host = Windows 8.1, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz, 64-bit o.s., RAM = 8 GB) (and guest = Ubuntu 14.04-LTS).

When I try to run a (particularly big) program written in Fortran (which would require 13-14 hours as I estimated), at the very beginning (when some matrices are built) the message "Killed" appears, and the program stops.

What is the problem here?

I think it should not be a problem of storage because I have 23.5 GB used and 22.5 GB free.

Maybe it is a shortage of RAM?

I've also tried to set the memory of the Virtual Machine to the "maximum recommended memory = 6320 MB (Memory swapping may occur beyond this size.)", but, same result.

Comment: How many CPU cores did you give the guest?

Comment: I see I can choose between "Number of Processor cores = 1,2,3,4,6,8". Now it is set to 2.